# dynamic loading of script files by cookies/droplist

Tags: javascript, cookies, dynamic, drop-down-menu

Im trying to get the following started:

I have a dropdown list which should change a script file and reexecute it based on the droplist choice. It also needs to store the selection variable in a cookie, so in a next visit the right script is launched on loading of the page. At any time the dropdown list can be changed (including the cookie) to change the script once more.

I have attempted to write the script, but the script doesn't work. Some help in fixing this script would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() 
{
    var user=getCookie("droplist-keuze");
    if (user != "") 
    {
    loadScript("script'+user+'.js", function());
    } else 
    {
        loadScript("script.js", function());
    }
}

</script>

<script> 
function loadJS(v){
    var d=document, h=d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0], newScript;
    try {h.removeChild(d.getElementById('lib_lang'));} catch (e){}
    newScript      = d.createElement('script');
    newScript.id   = 'lib_lang';
    newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    newScript.src  = 'script'+v+'.js';   // change your path here
    h.appendChild(newScript);
  setCookie("droplist-keuze", v, 30;
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkCookie()">
<select lang="en" onchange="loadJS(this.value)">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="true"> Select</option>
    <option value="1">1  </option>
    <option value="2">2  </option>
    <option value="3">3  </option>
    <option value="4">4  </option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `"script'+user+'.js"` => `"script"+user+".js"`

Comment: thanks, i also added a ")" in the setcookie, but still the script isn't working as it should. anyone know what the problem is?